# pythonのマルチスレッドのメソッドから戻り値を得るにはどうしたらよいですか？

Tags: python

スレッドはthreadingでメソッドを複数生成して、ほぼ並列処理みたいな感じというのはなんとなくわかったのですが、メソッドの戻り値がほしいときは、どのようにしてとったらよいのでしょうか？理想は全ての戻り値を足すことができればと思っているのですが・・・

まず考え方が間違っているのでしょうか？

```
def pulus(x, y):
    sums = x + y
    return sums

pulus_threads = []
for i in range(1, 3):
    pulus_thread = threading.Thread(target=pulus, args=(i, i))
    pulus_threads.append(pulus_thread)
    pulus_thread.start()
for pulus_thread in pulus_threads:
    pulus_thread.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

用途によりけりなのですが、今回の場合は`concurrent.futures`の[`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#executor-objects)を使うと楽に実装できます。

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def pulus(x, y):
    sums = x + y
    return sums

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    x = range(5)
    y = range(5, 10)
    res = executor.map(pulus, x, y)


print(list(x))
print(list(y))
print(list(res))
```

`ThreadPoolExecutor`はI/Oがボトルネックのときによく使われます。重い処理を複数のCPUに分散させることが目的でしたら、`ProcessPoolExecutor`のほうがいいかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。実際にコードを試してみましたがこれはわかりやすいですね。マルチスレッド処理にも色々やり方があるのだなということがわかりました。

Comment: 使用方法が簡単なので間違えにくいのが長所ですね。非同期処理はトラップが多いので苦労するとは思いますが、ぜひ頑張ってみて下さい^^;

Answer (score 0):

"python multithread return value"で検索すると、色々と出てきます。
英語版のStackOverflowにいくつか良さそうなのがありました。

1.multiprocessingモジュールのThreadpoolを使う方法
ベストアンサーではapply_asyncでスレッドプールを作成し、getで結果を取得しています。
ただし、ベストアンサーについても、色々と議論の余地があるようです。
how to get the return value from a thread in python?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python
関連
How to obtain the results from a pool of threads in python?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104512/how-to-obtain-the-results-from-a-pool-of-threads-in-python/26104609#26104609

2.QueueモジュールのQueueを使う方法
ベストアンサーでは先にQueueを作成し、各スレッドのパラメータにそのQueueを指定し、スレッドは結果をQueueに詰める。
呼び出し元はすべてのスレッドが終了してからQueueの結果が無くなるまで合計なり平均なりのやりたい処理を行う。
こちらも議論の余地があるようです。
Return value from thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886090/return-value-from-thread

3.参考
pythonのモジュールに関する解説サイトから
threading – Manage concurrent threads
https://pymotw.com/2/threading/
multiprocessing — Manage Processes Like Threads
https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/index.html

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。参考サイト拝見しましたが、自分にとってはQueueモジュールがあってそうな感じがしました。